# Animated human characters in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Where is the code to [animate human characters as seen in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7WEjAeztrc)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3159/animated-human-characters-in-gazebo/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

[here](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters) is the tutorial, but it is currently supported only under Gazebo 1.0.
I am not sure where I read it but I think it will be supported again starting version 2.0

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-06-07**:
That's correct. We fell behind maintaining the character animation code. We will revise the code sometime after June. Please fork gazebo, and start work on the animation code if you need it sooner.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2013-06-11**:
@nkoenig So what would forking actually involve? Updating SDF and writing some new plugins?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2013-07-02**:
Forked discussion to here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3426/reimplementing-character-animation/

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2014-03-19**:
Has this been updated to work again? What about animating a non-human character like a simple box?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-03-25**:
It's not working yet. You can animate a box using the [Entity::SetAnimation](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Entity.html#a0ba2d580de851fabb0ef90f8e53bedcd) function

**Comment by [akeefe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2884/akeefe/) on 2016-10-25**:
I found a tutorial that says it applies "to Gazebo versions 8+" so it appears this feature is making a comeback